# cmake on Mac with ARM M1 is running linker with x86_64 architecture instead of arm64

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw, apple-m1

I am trying to compile [glfw](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) from source on Mac with M1 arm64 processor, and while running the linker, cmake strangely is trying to link the project for x86_64 architecture, while the binaries were built for arm64.

I clone the project, create build folder named `cmake-build-debug`, generate build system in it with the Makefile etc. as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
cd glfw
mkdir cmake-build-debug
cd cmake-build-debug
cmake -S .. -B . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm64 -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm64
```

This works fine. But now that I build it with `make` or `cmake --config Debug --build .`, the `.o` binaries are generated perfectly fine, but linker script is incorrectly invoked by cmake with x86_64 target architecture for some reason:

```
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Including Cocoa support
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/burkov/Documents/Projects/open-source/glfw/cmake-build-debug
[ 47%] Built target glfw
Scanning dependencies of target wave
[ 50%] Linking C executable wave.app/Contents/MacOS/wave
ld: warning: ignoring file CMakeFiles/wave.dir/wave.c.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file ../src/libglfw3.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [examples/wave.app/Contents/MacOS/wave] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/wave.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I look at the failing Makefile in `glfw/cmake-build-debug/examples/CMakeFiles/wave.dir/build.make` and see the line, where cmake is crashing:

```
cd /Users/me/Documents/Projects/open-source/glfw/cmake-build-debug/examples && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/wave.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
```

I manually open the file `glfw/cmake-build-debug/examples/CMakeFiles/wave.dir/link.txt` file and see the following link script code there:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -g -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/wave.dir/wave.c.o  -o wave.app/Contents/MacOS/wave  ../src/libglfw3.a -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation
```

If I manually execute this line from shell, it successfully builds my binary for arm64 architecture, as expected.

But when this `link.txt` script is automatically invoked with `cmake` via `cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/wave.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)`, it fails, apparently, trying to build the binary for the wrong x86_64 architecture.

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Usually a) `-S ... -B ...` goes *last*; at least that's the usage suggested by the documentation. b) The choice of target system goes into the [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) alongside sysroot, compiler paths, initial compiler flags, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone running into the same problem, it [looks like](https://hsf-training.github.io/hsf-training-cmake-webpage/01-intro/index.html) the first version of `cmake` with an adequate support for Apple Silicon is [3.19](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.19.html).

I was using 3.17.5 as my slightly out-of-date version of CLion does not support versions of cmake above that.

After an update to cmake 3.22.4 the problem is gone.