# C project suddenly not compiling on macOS "building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64"

Tags: c, macos, compilation, x86-64

### Problem

For the past couple of weeks, I've been working on an erasure coding project that is built on top of the [Intel ISA-L](https://github.com/intel/isa-l) library.

Everything was going fine as I was just debugging for a while, and then I left the project for about one day. I returned to continue debugging, and without making any changes to the code or to my Macbook (that I know of), I tried to compile the code once more as part of my debugging process, and I got the following error:

```
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup is incompatible with dyld share cache
ld: warning: ignoring file raid/.libs/raid_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file erasure_code/.libs/ec_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file crc/.libs/crc_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file crc/.libs/crc64_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/hufftables_c.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/igzip.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/igzip_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/igzip_icf_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/adler32_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/encode_df.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/flatten_ll.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/igzip_icf_body.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file mem/.libs/mem_zero_detect_base.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/huff_codes.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file igzip/.libs/igzip_inflate.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: -undefined dynamic_lookup cannot be used to find '_ec_encode_data_base' in dylib in dyld shared cache for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libisal.la] Error 1
```

I've tried several potential solutions that I saw on Stack Overflow and other sources online, but none of them have worked. I also tried to compile the code on the standard ISA-L library without any of my additional code added to it, but the same problem occurs.

### Additional information:

- I am working on a 2020 MacBook pro running on macOS Monterey 12.5 with the M1 Apple chip.
- This is the output of `clang --version`:

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

- This is the output of `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

- The Makefile is quite complicated, and I think was autogenerated by some code in the Intel ISA-L library, so I didn't include it here, but I am hoping that this is a problem that isn't specific to my situation and that there is a general fix to this that could apply to many situations.
- Let me know if any other details are needed.

Comment: Not seeing any compiler errors. `ld` is the linker.  Somewhere you are mixing arm and x86_64 libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the link works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886952/20189614

I solved the problem after updating cmake to version 3.24.2.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that helped me solve this issue (although it uncovered a deeper unrelated bug), that I think might be helpful for others.

Obviously, since I'm running on an M1 MacBook Pro, the output of `clang --version` should have been `arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0` instead of `x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0`.

Running the command `arch` was also returning `i3864` instead of `arm64`, which was an issue.

To solve this, I ran the following command:

```
env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login
```

I'm not sure if this is a thorough solution or just a quick-fix, but after rebooting I got clang to compile with ARM.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem (with mpicc) and I solved it changing the architecture of clang with the option -arch arm64. You can check the change by entering clang -arch arm64 --version (or mpicc -arch arm64 --version, in my case)

```
clang version 14.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
```