# Configured with clang 13, error from "Building for macOS-x86_64 but with file built for -arm64 "

Tags: gcc, makefile, x86, arm

If I verify my `gcc --version` I get:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

And when I build with `make` after `configure`, I obtain the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_2/lib/gcc/11/libquadmath.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: in '/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_2/lib/gcc/11/libquadmath.0.dylib', building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[8]: *** [libfgsl.la] Error 1
make[7]: *** [subdir-fgsl] Error 2
make[6]: *** [build-fgsl] Error 2
make[5]: *** [hd-std-all-subdirs] Error 2
make[4]: *** [all-subdirs] Error 2
make[3]: *** [hd-std-all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [heacore] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Following the similar question here, I verified that

```
% ranlib --version
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: unknown option character `-' in: --version
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib [-sactfqLT] [-] archive [...]
(base) user@user BUILD_DIR % ranlib -version 
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: unknown option character `v' in: -version
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib [-sactfqLT] [-] archive [...]
```

and that `echo $PATH` returns:

```
% echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

I have followed similar questions and [a) updated Cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886569/cmake-on-mac-with-arm-m1-is-running-linker-with-x86-64-architecture-instead-of-a), b) attempted to edit `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES` (but not found in cmake), and more.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

EDIT: for `env`:

```
% env
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/zsh
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/9x/gdg5j9sd4wx3q_v9f2pkrw6r0000gn/T/
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=445
TERM_SESSION_ID=C5417ED9-E4C8-411C-9CC3-18711A679E88
USER=username
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.nCSXSuYzna/Listeners
PATH=/usr/bin:/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Comment: From the information provided, all I think we can say for sure is that you have development tools and / or libraries for two different hardware architectures installed on your machine, and something about their configuration and / or your personal environment is causing one to attempt to use parts of the other, with disastrous results.  The full contents of your environment might help (running the `env` command in a Terminal will give you that).

Comment: Also, it looks like you may have installed Homebrew some time in the past.  Uninstalling that via its uninstallation tool might resolve your issue.  (But of course, that very well might have undesirable side effects, too.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you. env added. Not sure what one can really gain from it though. I also tried to repeat the `config` with `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.4 ./configure` but it returns the same error as before.

Comment: Ok, such a sparse environment makes things easier.  The only thing I see that looks potentially fruitful to twiddle is the `PATH`.  I'm going to suggest removing anaconda, X11, and /usr/local from it with this: `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`.  That will affect only the Terminal session in which it is executed.  After doing that, re-run `./configure`.

Comment: Thanks. However, I still get the same error when I `make` after the `./configure`.